# Android set NTP server for GPS

Tags: android, gps, google-play-services

I've been researching for an hour and a half now and I can't find how to change the NTP server for my app.

I know it CAN be done cause FasterGPS app can do it (it needs root, but i'm guessing it is only needed cause it would change a system file for all the apps, not just for itself).

How can I change the NTP server so I can set it `pa.pool.ntp.org`?

**PS:** I'm using **Google Play Services** for GPS location data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've been researching for an hour and a half now and I can't find how to change the NTP server for my app.

There is no "NTP server for [your] app" in conventional Android development. If you are getting the time from the system, it is up to the system to determine where that time comes from (NTP, NITZ, etc.).

If you find some SNTP library, you are welcome to point it to whatever NTP server that you want, and then use that library to obtain time from that server.

> I'm using Google Play Services for GPS location data

You cannot affect the time that Google Play Services uses. It will use whatever the Google developers chose to use, both in the library piece that is compiled into your app, and in the separate app that houses a lot of the Play Services functionality, such as the actual `LocationClient` work.